# Open source cloud storage(CS) for Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, amazon-s3, cloud-storage

Are there any open source cloud storage build with GAE/J?

I've found lots of open source cloud storage:

- Ceph S3 http://ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/
- Riak CS http://basho.com/riak-cloud-storage/

However, I can't find anything for GAE, are there any even those that doesn't easily pop out of a Google search?

**EDIT:** I was looking for server implementation of a cloud storage, not really a client.

Anyway a new project is starting that does cloud storage: https://code.google.com/p/basket-stack/

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are looking for.
Google already provides a cloud storage solution (http://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage.html), which has an S3 like api and can be used through GAE. There are also open source libraries for Java and Python (https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/).

Comment: I was looking for a server, not really a cloud storage client.